# Let $k$ be a field. The generic point of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$ does not form a constructible set of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\zeta=[(0)]$ be the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$.

If $\{\zeta\}$ were constructible, then we could write $\{\zeta\}$ as a finite disjoint union of locally closed subsets. But then $\zeta$ must be in just one of these locally closed subsets.

Say, $\zeta \in U \cap V$ where $U$ is open and $V$ is closed. Since $\zeta \in V$, then $V=\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$ and so $\{\zeta\} = U$ is open. Therefore, $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]-\{\zeta\}$ is closed.

Where should we go from here?

Comment: You know the closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$, yes? Is this one of them?

Comment: @KReiser Right. Forgot about that that fact. Now I got it.

Comment: @user46372819 If you've figured out the answer to your own question, I suggest you answer the question yourself and accept it, to (a) help out others in the future who may have the question, and (b) remove the question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\zeta=[(0)]$ be the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$.

If $\{\zeta\}$ were constructible, then we could write $\{\zeta\}$ as a finite disjoint union of locally closed subsets. But then $\zeta$ must be in just one of these locally closed subsets.

Say, $\zeta \in U \cap V$ where $U$ is open and $V$ is closed. Since $\zeta \in V$, then $V=\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$ and so $\{\zeta\} = U$ is open. Therefore, $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]-\{\zeta\}$ is closed.

Since $k[x]$ is a PID, any closed subset is of the form $V(f)$ for some polynomial $f(x)$. If $\deg(f) \ge 1$, factoring $f$ into irreducibles, we have that $V(f)$ is a finite set. So, the closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$ are of the form: $\varnothing$, finite subsets, and all of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$.

Since $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]-\{\zeta\}$ is infinite, it is not closed. Contradiction.

So, $\{\zeta\}$ is not constructible.